# Unit testing spring controllers - whether to use MockMvc or directly call methods

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

While writing unit tests for a Spring controller, is it better to use MockMvc, or directly call the controller functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer to use MockMvc as it is testing my Controller properly i.e. the Request mappings.

If you will call the controller directly then the annotations will not be tested.

Answer (score 0):

Testing using MockMvc is better for unit testing controllers since, as mentioned in the accepted answer, it will test the request mappings as well rather than just the function code.
For lightweight unit tests, it is better to use the standAloneSetup Builder in MockMvcBuilder, so that there is no need of loading Application Context. For integration tests, we can use webAppContextSetup (according to http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/030-testing-spring-rest-webservice-controllers/)

**Sample code** (Mockito, jsonpath, jackson also)

```
userService = mock(UserService.class);
userController = new UserController(userService);
mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standAloneSetup(userController);
// stub userService calls
LoginRequest body = new LoginRequest();
// set loginrequest fields
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mockMvc.perform(post("/login").content(mapper.writeValueAsString(loginRequest)
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.userId").value("expected_value"));
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11616495)

Comment: ^Oh sure, I just found this link helpful, that's all.. I did include a one liner but will expand upon it.